# slickgrid data not visible

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slickgrid, directive

I have written a slickgrid directive, but it does not seem to be displaying the data.

if i do inspect element in chrome, then i can see the `slick-viewport`, and `grid-canvas` divs, where my data is rendered.

i did try `resizeCanvas` which had no effect.

Basically grid rows are renedered but it is not visible.

My modal looks like this

```
    <div id="TestModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 900px; margin-left: -450px">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Results</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <myGrid
                           rows="results"  //results =  tow way bind to controller
                           columns="columns"  //columns =two way bind to controller
                           width="1100px"
                           height="200px"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button ng-class="dialogButtonClass" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Select</button>
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            </div>
   </div>
```

and the codel launch it looks like this     `$('#TestModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');`

Then i follow the documented way of rendering the  data

i.e

```
var view= this.grid.getData();
           // To set the entire the data then use this
            view.beginUpdate();
            view.setItems(data, "id");
            view.collapseGroup(0);
            view.endUpdate();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that when you inspect the top-level `<div>` (the one you initialize `new Slick.Grid()` with) it has a set width and height. Also make sure you're calling `myGrid.resizeCanvas()` only after the modal has been shown and all the CSS transitions have completed:

```
$('#TestModal').on('shown', myGrid.resizeCanvas)
```

Comment: I had this problem and I did not have a set height, after setting that value it worked, thank you.